# Terraform data block not picking up value from locals file

Tags: terraform

I have "datasources.tf" which picks up existing resources like VPC, Subnet etc and a "locals.tf" that have environment value assigned. I am passing name for vpc in data block as below :

```
data "aws_vpc" "main" {
  tags = {
    Name = local.workspace["vpc_name"]
  }
}
```

And the local file is like below:

```
locals {

  workspace  = local.env[terraform.workspace]
  aws_region = "ap-southeast-2"

  env = {
    glue-dev = {
      aws_profile = "default"
      region      = "ap-southeast-2"
      env         = "DEV1"
      vpc_name    = "DEV1-VPC"
      name_prefix = "glue-dev"
      account_id  = "AWS_account_id"
   }
}
```

While performing the terraform plan, this fails stating below

```
 │ Error: no matching VPC found
 │ 
 │   with data.aws_vpc.main,
 │   on datasources.tf line 8, in data "aws_vpc" "main":
 │    8: data "aws_vpc" "main" {
```

The VPC exists but due to some reason the data block is not picking the VPC also after hard coding the value. Please check if I am missing something.

Comment: That's the full error message? Its strangely very short and non-specific.

Comment: Have updated the error message. That's all I am getting.

Answer (score 1):

`local.workspace["vpc_name"]` does not reference anything.

May be something like:

```
data "aws_vpc" "main" {
  tags = {
    Name = local.env["glue-dev"].vpc_name
  }
}
```

?